# Solve Improper Integrate using Residue theorem for this integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve this integral

$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\cdot sin(x)}{x^2+4} \cdot dx $

I have applied the residue theorem on a semicircle of radius $R> 2$, $\gamma$, so I have

$ \int_\gamma \frac{z\cdot sin(z)}{z^2+4} \cdot dz = \int_{-R}^R \frac{x\cdot sin(x)}{x^2+4} \cdot dx+  \int_{C_R} \frac{z\cdot sin(z)}{z^2+4} \cdot dz$

where $C_R = \{ z : z=R e^{i \theta} , \theta \in (0,\pi)\}$, but I cannot limit the second integral to eliminate this contribution when $R \to \infty$ and I don't know how I could do the integral in another way

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I have to post it on mathOverflow not mathematica. Thank you

Comment: @user, this is ***not*** a question that is for research mathematicians to answer, so MathOverflow is ***not*** the right site. I'm moving this to math.SE instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a function $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ as follows : $$ \left(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ f\left(t\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xt}}{x^{2}+4}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

Fixing $ t\in\mathbb{R} $ and $ R> 2 $, then integrating $ f_{t}:z\mapsto\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}zt}}{z^{2}+4} $ on $ \gamma_{R}=\left[-R,R\right]\cup\mathscr{C}_{R} $, where $ \mathscr{C}_{R}=\left\lbrace z:\left|z\right|=R,\ \mathcal{Im}\left(z\right)\geq 0\right\rbrace $, will give us a closed form for our $ f \cdot $

We have : $$ 2\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Res}\left(f_{t},2\mathrm{i}\right)=\oint_{\gamma_{R}}{f_{t}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}=\int_{-R}^{R}{f_{t}\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f_{t}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z} $$

Since : $$ \left|\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{f_{t}\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}\right|\leq\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{\left|f_{t}\left(z\right)\right|\left|\mathrm{d}z\right|}\leq\frac{1}{R^{2}-4}\int_{\mathscr{C}_{R}}{\left|\mathrm{d}z\right|}=\frac{1}{R^{2}-4}\int_{0}^{\pi}{R\,\mathrm{d}\theta}=\frac{\pi R}{R^{2}-4}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow }0 $$

And : $$ 2\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Res}\left(f_{t},2\mathrm{i}\right)=2\pi\mathrm{i}\lim_{z\to 2\mathrm{i}}{\left(z-2\mathrm{i}\right)f_{t}\left(z\right)}=2\pi\mathrm{i}\lim_{z\to 2\mathrm{i}}{\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}zt}}{z+2\mathrm{i}}}=\frac{\pi\,\mathrm{e}^{-2t}}{2} $$

Tending $ R $ to infinity, we get : $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f_{t}\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\pi\,\mathrm{e}^{-2t}}{2} $$

And hence, for any real $ t $, we have : $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{x\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}xt}}{x^{2}+4}\,\mathrm{d}x}=-\mathrm{i}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{\partial f_{t}}{\partial t}\left(t,x\right)\mathrm{d}x}=-\mathrm{i}f'\left(t\right)=\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{e}^{-2t} $$

Taking the imaginary part, we get that $ \forall t\in\mathbb{R} $ : $$ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\frac{x\sin{\left(xt\right)}}{x^{2}+4}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\pi\,\mathrm{e}^{-2t}\end{array}$} $$

Comment: The result is correct only for positive $t$ (the integral is odd in $t$).